# ruby on rails no method error due to routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting a no method error when trying to display a destroy link.

Here's the code to my view

```
   <% @followed_locations.each do |followed_location| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= followed_location.user_id %></td>
        <td><%= followed_location.location_id %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', api_v1_followed_location_path(followed_location) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_api_v1_followed_location_path(followed_location) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', followed_location, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

and here's my code for the routes

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :followed_locations do
      collection do
        post "by_user_id"
        post "by_location_id"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the namespaces in my routes but i'm unsure how to fix it and I can't seem to find anything online about this. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please include the actual error, e.g., the stack trace.

Comment: The delete path is the combination of the show path and the use of the method `:delete`. In your case: `api_v1_followed_location_path(followed_location), method: :delete`

Comment: (But yes, it's nested, so you must use the complete path to the resource.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<%= link_to "Destory", api_v1_followed_location_path(followed_location), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since if you have namspaces api and v1, you will need to include in the path as well.
So it should be like:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', api_v1_followed_location, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

EDIT: Code wasn't showing up, fixed now